# How to create a relations between primary key and foreign key in Django models and POST values into DB

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have a Django app which is basically an Online shopping. Right now I have two models: `User_details` and `Extend_user_details`.

In User_details I have(Username, Firstname, lastname, email, etc..). Now after that i need to extend  **User_details** Model with Other Fields so I have Created another Model  **Extend_user_deatils** consisting of (Mobile , Age) columns.

Now I need to Link those Two Models, for that I have written a logic with Foreign Key Reference as:

```
class User_details(models.Model):                                                     #Table 1
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='user_id')
    username = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50)


class Extend_user_details(models.Model):                                              #Table 2
    user =models.ForeignKey(User_details, on_delete=models.CASCADE,db_column='user_id')
    mobile = models.BigIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I Open Django admin Page and Post the Data it is Working Fine and Values are posting into DB.

When I register as a User from register page . ForeignKey Column(user) from Table2 is showing Null .apart from that all the inputs is posting into DB as shown [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DU6FZ.jpg)

Is there any way to solve this issue?

Comment: Share the view logic which renders the register page template.

Comment: Here it is 

       cli1 = User_details.objects.create(username=username, email=email,first_name=first_name, last_name=last_name)
        cli1.save()





        cli2 = Extend_user_details.objects.create(age=age, mobile=mobile)
        cli2.save()

Comment: Please edit this in the question, it is not understandable in comment.

Answer (score 1):

sometimes when you are creating foreignKey, Django will make a separate table in DB to store the foreignkey values especially when you use the  shell to do queries

Comment: This answer should be a comment.

Comment: I don't have that much points to comment lol